# Binding material-select to my model

Tags: dart, material-design, angular-dart, angular-components

I've got a simple use case - I have a rich object model I'm using in an AngularDart application, and I want a  component to show me the current state of one of the model's fields AND I want to call a method on the model when the selection changes (which will eventually update the field bound to the ).

Something like this:

app-component.dart:

```
@Component(
  selector: 'my-app',
  styleUrls: const ['app_component.css'],
  templateUrl: 'app_component.html',
  directives: const [CORE_DIRECTIVES, materialDirectives],
  providers: const [materialProviders],
)
class AppComponent {
  Model myModel = new MyModel();
  SelectionModel<String> selectModel = new SelectionModel();
}
```

app-component.html:

```
<material-dropdown-select
   [options]='myModel.listOfOptions'
   [buttonText]='myModel.currentOption'
   [selection]='selectModel'>
   <!-- call myModel.changeOption(selectedOption) when selection changes -->
</material-dropdown-select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
selectModel.selectionChanges.listen(update);

void update(List<SelectionChangeRecord> record) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Hi, could you share your code in github? I'm having an error of: 
`EXCEPTION: Assertion failed: org-dartlang-app:///packages/angular_components/material_select/material_dropdown_select_accessor.dart:118:12 _select.selection == null "Cannot set [selection] when using a Dropdown control value accessor."`

Answer (score 0):

Attach a setter to your `selectModel` member, and run the code in there as well as updating the "real" value (private member).  You'll need the matching getter of course.

Comment: I'm still a little confused ... who calls the setter?

Comment: I know I'm probably being dense, but something like this?

    SelectionModel<String> _selectModel = new SelectionModel();
    SelectionModel<String> get selectModel {
      return _selectModel;
    }
    set selectModel(SelectionModel<String> model) {
      _selectModel = model;
      _selectModel.selectionChanges.listen(updateSelection);
    }

If so, its not working. The setter is not being called in response to changing the selection.

Comment: It's possible that you're expecting the code to update the value at the wrong point in the angular lifecycle.  Perhaps https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular/guide/lifecycle-hooks will make it clearer.   You might be looking for a change before the change has had a chance to propogate.

Comment: I'm putting a "print" statement in the setter and it is not printing anything to the console. Is there a minimal working example you can provide?

Answer (score 0):

I hope if this [live example](https://webdev.dartlang.org/examples/ng/doc/toh-2) could help you, if interested see the [source code](https://github.com/angular-examples/toh-2/blob/master/lib/app_component.dart).